# Bash script with Perl multi-line regex (OSX)

Tags: regex, perl, bash, multiline

I have a file containing this XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <tag1>some text</tag1>
    <tag2><![CDATA[http://url1.com]]></tag2>
    <tag3 />
    <tag4>not empty node</tag4>
  </item>
  <item>
    <tag1>some other text</tag1>
    <tag2><![CDATA[http://www.url.com]]></tag2>
    <tag3 />
    <tag4 />
  </item>
</root>
```

(and a lot more XML inside)

I am trying to write a Bash script to remove some of the XML. Namely, I want to remove every `<item>` element that has an empty `<tag4>` child element.

Therefore I want to find `<item>` then find `<tag4/>` then find `</item>`, group this and replace with an `X` char.

I haven't even got up to the grouping yet, I have got stuck on doing a regex over multiple lines.

Running on Mac OSX

This is what I have got:

```
 perl -pn -e "s/<item>[\s\S]*<tag4 \/>/X/g" $XML_FILENAME > new_folder/$XML_FILENAME
```

if I remove the `[\s\S]*` (which means any space character or any character, I can replace the `<item>` tag, but I can't get to the next tag or next line.

(I also tried `echo//` and `sed` getting stuck in a similar position)

Comment: You must escape the slash: `<tag4 \/>`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte sure, just a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
s/<item>(?>[^<]++|<(?!tag4))*<tag4 \/>(?>[^<]++|<(?!\/item>))*<\/item>/X/g
```

This pattern avoids the newline problem because it doesn't use the dot.

**Explanations**

detail of `(?>[^<]++|<(?!tag4))*`

```
(?>                # open an atomic group
      [^<]++       # all that is not a < one or more times (possessive)
    |              # OR
      <(?!tag4)    # a < not followed by tag4
)*                 # close the atomic group, repeat zero or more times
```

Using this trick, I am sure that what follows is `<tag4` (or the end of the string)

I use [atomic groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) `(?>..)` and [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) `++` for more performances, but you can replace them by normal groups `(?:..)` and greedy quantifiers `+`

**Notices**

Or you can just use a lazy quantifier replacing `[\s\S]*` by `[\s\S]*?`

Note that with perl you can use the dotall mode instead of `[\s\S]` adding the s modifier:

```
 (?s).*          # the dot matches newlines
 (?-s).*         # the dot doesn't match newlines (default behavior)
```

Comment: Nope sorry your first reg ex doesn't work. Could you explain each part of it though? maybe I can make it work

Comment: @Blundell: sorry i have made a mistake, it is corrected. Explanations coming soon.

Comment: Works I just had to add `BEGIN{undef $/;}` before `s/..`

Comment: The reason it didn't work and why the dot isn't relevant is it's (command) line oriented in the OP. `perl -0777 ...` will do the equivalent of the BEGIN block you discovered.

Answer (score 3):

Better use an actual XML parser for this (e.g. [`XML::LibXML`](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod)) and select empty `<tag4>` nodes with an [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) expression:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file('/path/to/input.xml');

$_->unbindNode for $xml->findnodes('//item[not(tag4/text())]');

print $xml->toString;
```

If you want to directly save the modified XML to a file, replace the line

```
print $xml->toString;
```

with

```
$xml->toFile('/path/to/output.xml');
```

Comment: `$_->unbindNode for $xml->findnodes('/root/item[not(tag4/text())]')`

Comment: nice idea, didn't realise you could get this in a bash script

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions to process XML is impractical. You should use a proper Perl module.

This short program uses [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig) to process the file whose name is passed as a command-line parameter. It sends the modified XML to `STDOUT`.

```
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig= XML::Twig->new(pretty_print => 'indented');
$twig->parsefile($ARGV[0]);

for my $twig ($twig->findnodes('/root/item')) {
  $twig->delete unless $twig->findvalue('tag4') =~ /\S/;
}

$twig->print;
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <tag1>some text</tag1>
    <tag2><![CDATA[http://url1.com]]></tag2>
    <tag3/>
    <tag4>not empty node</tag4>
  </item>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way with `GNU awk`:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    ORS=""
    RS="<[/]?item>"
    f1="<item>"
    f2="<\/item>"
}
!/<tag4 \/>/ && NF { 
    print ($0~/tag/)?f1 $0 f2:$0
}' xmlfile
```

Answer (score 0):

this works but needs a little work :

```
 perl -00 -ne 's/<item>.*<\/tag4>.*<\/item>/X/gs;print "$_\n";' test.xml
```